# GDAL TIF to JPG Creates Dark Image

Tags: raster, geotiff-tiff, jpg, gdal-translate

I'm using the GDAL Raster>Translate to create JPGs from Georeferenced TIFs. The translation is working, but the resulting JPGs are significantly darker than the TIFs they are being created from.

Here is a screen shot showing the difference in brightness:
[image]

Anyone know why this is happening and (more importantly) how I can fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: how are you viewing your images ? The data values should not have been modified, but the rendering might depend on the input type and default software settings.

Comment: Can you share a sample of original imagery so we can try to reproduce the behaviour that you see?

Comment: I've uploaded one of the TIFs as well as the resulting JPG here:http://civilvisions.com/public/qgis/

Comment: Since JPG does not support transparency, is PNG an alternative for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloaded the raster from your link and used GDAL_Translate from the command line and the image was **awful**.

Your source image is 32bit RGBA, JPEG does not support RGBA so I tried -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 to *pluck* out the RGB bands from the 32bit:

[image: JPEG converted from tiff]

the QGIS translator gives you the option to edit the command so insert -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 into this line and your JPEG images will be much better.

```
GDAL_TRANSLATE -OF JPEG -B 1 -B 2 -B 3 d:\path\image.tif d:\other_path\image.jpg
```

Comment: Brilliant! That worked. I had suspected something like an alpha problem or some such thing, so I used the QGIS Browser to view the info about the file. According to that, it's an 8-bit image. Even PhotoShop reports that it's an 8-bit image, but opening it up there does indeed show an alpha channel. Thanks a million!

Comment: Background info also in mail thread http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gis.gdal.devel/37858