# GDALwarp Creates Darker target Image sometimes

Tags: gdalwarp

I'm yoyo and new to this forum. I'm relatively new to GIS and GDAL. Please accept some typos now and then... English is not my native language.

Because of some problems with GDAL 1.7.0b2 in FWTools 2.4.7 I upgraded to GDAL 1.11.0 in the latest OSGeo4W distro. This solved some issues I had, but introduced a really anoying one and what ever I do I can't get rid off it. I hope someone can help me out. If btw I try to go back to GDAL 1.7.0b2 with FWTools the problem is still there, so I guess it's a driver/DLL update issue.

My problem looks exactly like this post... [GDAL TIF to JPG Creates Dark Image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101393/gdal-tif-to-jpg-creates-dark-image)
Only that I don't use JPG. And I use GDALwarp. And not all target files have the problem. Most target files look ok. 
And I only see it with Aerial Photo like sources. With vector like raster sources I don't see the problem. So when reading the other post I thought it had to do with a mask/alpha channel or something, but I can't see this in the source. And whatever option I test, the problem remains.

Section of Source : https://www.dropbox.com/s/gy2tu0h8dufv41o/Source.jpg?dl=0

Intersection of four Target files : https://www.dropbox.com/s/av7mdj8ivx3zgsl/Target.jpg?dl=0

I tested almost all options in multiple actions in my workflow. 
So cutting the source with gdaltranslate in smaller parts for editing. Building a VRT with gdalbuildvrt and cutting into final parts with gdalwarp which will show the problem.

I started with the -b 1 -b 2 -b 3 option in my gdalbuildvrt action, but GDAL crashes here... (?)
I also tested other options that might have something to do with the problem... 
-nomd -co ALPHA=YES/No -co PHOTOMETRIC=RGBA/RGB -setci, you name it...

I checked good and bad source and target areas with gdalcompare and gdalinfo, but I saw nothing strange...

I'm now thinking of resetting GDAL driver settings if that is possible..(?)

Has anyone seen this before? Can anyone give me a hint..?

PROBLEM FOUND.

I'm using a workaround now...
I found out that the problem was there with one specific target size. So I started testing with filters and when I used an other filter then cubicspline, the problem was gone. So the problem was a combination with the cubicspline filter and a specific target resolution.

Comment: are your tiff values slightly above 0.5? Where are the tiffs from?

Comment: @buther. 
Which tiff value do you mean?, Gamma? (0.5 would be very low), Blacks? (0-255). Originally the tiffs came from the internet as 24bit JPEG. They where merged with ImageMagick Montage into 24bit Tiff.

Comment: So the source is 8bit/channel RGB JPEG. And the merged Tiff is 8bit/channel RGB. No Alpha...

Comment: TIFF can have every value and different "layers". But if those are RGB I am out of the game. converting a TIFF which helds probabilities resulted in black jpgs in my case. remove the alpha channel as jpg doesn't know alpha.